# No way to override Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, overriding

First off, I did research this topic here and via Google for an entire day, and tried all I have found, for some reason I still can not seem to change Bootstrap styling. My custom css DOES work, since the first modification from it worked just beautifully where it did not need to override anything (so there was no default styling for input:hover, which I used, in bootstrap.)

Here is some code:

```
.input-group-prepend.form-control:focus {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 11px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), inset 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

NOTE that the selector here must be like the 20th version I tried. Here I can not change the way the input field behaves when in focus. I tried everything after like a dozen searches on Google, nothing worked. I also used Chrome Inspect to find where box-shadow is used, and inside Inspect I could also `CHANGE` the property, which resulted the look I desired, but after copying that part to my css with the css selector, it did not work anymore. Having tried also tweaking the selectors to make them more specific, calculated the 'Priority points' or whatever they are called even, used IDs and whatever, and put my stylesheet link after the bootstrap one in the html file - no change (for the better, that is). These all worked for other people here and on YouTube and everywhere on the internet, and seemingly I have the very same situation and solution and for me they still don't. I am thinking of leaving bootstrap and try building something from scratch, but I am not that experienced in CSS, and I feel like I never want to be if it is like this.[enter image description here][1]

Some more code:

```
button .btn-raised {
    box-shadow: 0 30px 0 0 #007299;
}
```

The second part, when trying to set the box-shadow for buttons, it is not possible, even though neither btn or btn-light, which I use, does do anything with box-shadow, Chrome Inspect simply shows 'none' as the value of this property. (Although I found that there is some transition where it is involved, but no way I can override or disable it.) Again, a hell of a lot of selector variations was tried.

---

UPDATE: The problem is solved, turned out all the problems I had was because I missed clearing the cache before reloading the page - never forget that! :)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using? can you post a screenshot of how you want the input to look?

Comment: I hope it's not the button you're asking since I cannot reach that look :) (Though I want it to look like a real button, protruding and getting lit from above, as though by the sun).

The text input I made a screenshot of, and I updated my question with it (see end of it)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me. I think you may be loading your CSS before Bootstrap or you have other styles overriding your latest styles due to specificity.

As a last resort, just to test this theory, you could try adding !important after your styles. If this works then you know it's an issue with selector specificity but I don't recommend using !important in general.

eg:

```
div {
    background-color: #000 !important;
}
```

```css
button {
  box-shadow: 2px 5px 1px 0 #007299;
}

.input-group-prepend {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.input-group-prepend .form-control:focus {
    color: #495057;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 11px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), inset 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button class="btn btn-light">I am a button</button>

<div class="input-group-prepend">
 <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes the example you provided is pretty much what I want too.
I tried !important, too, I just didn't mention it (tried so many things it's hard to recall everything). 
Same with the order, I have it after the bootstrap link, but I tried putting it before that, too, no result. 
The overrides I can not find with the Chrome Inspect window, or at least what I found means no solution after changing them.

Comment: Make sure you are clearing your browser cache each time you make a change.

Comment: Try commenting out all your custom styles only leaving the ones that don't appear to work

Comment: OK, let's begin with the good news. Clearing the cache worked. I can now style the button, KUDOS for you, Sir! :) I should've thought that something like that was in the way... But the text inputs still use the default bootstrap highlighting that I wanted to replace. Commenting out the working parts did not change the non-working one.

Comment: Yes the cache caught me out a lot in my early days. The next part could depend on your html. Notice how in my example the input group prepend class is a container for the input which changes the css selector to have a space between the class names rather than your original CSS without a space eg: .input-group-prepend .form-control: instead of .input-group-prepend.form-control so it depends on where you have your input-group-prepend class in the html

Comment: It was an issue with the selectors, input-group-prepend was not what I wanted to style, because it was the element next to the textbox. Earlier I tried with the good selector, back when I did not know of the trick of cache clearing. So in the end every problem I had came down to that. Thank you very much for all the help given!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it is all working. Please remember to up vote my answer and mark as correct if I helped